# Trying to move rows with VBA but I am getting an error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: vba, cell, move

So I have a code that goes through a spreadsheet (About 150,000 lines) and highlights specific ones red. Now, I'm trying to move those selected lines and here is the code I have:

```
Dim x As Long, iInsertedRows As Integer

x = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For x = x To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(x, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then '3 is standard red color
        Rows(x).Cut

        '''The next row is where it breaks'''
        Rows("1:1").Insert shift:=xlDown 'paste the cut row back as row 1

        x = x + 1 'we've just moved everything down a row
        iInsertedRows = iInsertedRows + 1
        If iInsertedRows = x Then Exit For 'we don't need to sort the ones we put there
    End If
Next
```

(Source: http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/6791-move-rows-top-cells-columna-filled-red.html)

The issue is that I am getting an error that reads:
Run-time error '1004':
This selection is not valid.
There are several possible reasons:

- Copy and paste areas cannot overlap unless they are the same size
- If you are using the Create from Selection Command, the row or column containing the proposed names will not be included in the... (It gets cut off by the bottom of the error box).

Comment: Quick pointer about error messages: You can copy the entire error message by pressing Ctrl+C while it is displayed, then paste it to the editor of your choice for reading/saving.  This should let you read the entirety of the message, even though the error box format appears to truncate it.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.  I'm wondering if there is a specific row/location that is causing the problem.  Does this work with other data?  Can you edit your question to include a shot of the data you are using?  Have you stepped through the loop as it's progressing to see if it's a specific row that triggers it?